# Xcode Organizer different version number?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I am trying to upload a binary for iTunes Connect, but as I can see the version number is different from the one originally declared.

```
Version number declared in Xcode: 1.0
Version number shown in Organizer: 1.0 (1)
```

What does the `(1)` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that `(1)` stands for the build number.